# Angular pagination control page number to show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am using angular pagination in which if the page are too much then its showing pagination like google logic.

Here is the screenshot for the same

[image]

I want to restric the width of the pagination so i need to remove some extra numbers to show so is there any way to remove some pages like its showing 7 pages in start can i restrict it to 3 pages.

This is my complete code

**Pagination HTML**

```
<div class="paginationCont">
    <dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)" template-url="templates/pagination_ctrls.html"></dir-pagination-controls>
</div>
```

**Printing rows**

```
<tr ng-hide="transStatus=='inactive'" dir-paginate="item in transactions | filter: transSearch | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">
    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck"> {{item.txn_id}}</label></div></td>
     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
     <td>{{item.datetime | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
    <td>{{item.amount}}</td>
    <td>{{item.client_cut}}</td>
    <td ng-switch="item.status"><span ng-switch-when="1">Active</span><span ng-switch-when="0">Inactive</span></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use . **max-size**
*(optional, default = 9) Specify a maximum number of pagination links to display. The default is 9, and the minimum is 5 (setting a lower value than 5 will not have an effect).*

so your pagination html will be

```
<div class="paginationCont">
    <dir-pagination-controls max-size="5" boundary-links="true" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)" template-url="templates/pagination_ctrls.html"></dir-pagination-controls>
</div>
```

after adding max-size="5" pagination will look like this
[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: can we show the last three number and last three numbers in this pagination? Like 1 2 3 .. 14 15 16 .. 98 99 100